# Assigning null to primitive data type after auto-boxing it

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I was asked this question at [FirstRain](http://www.firstrain.com/)

When one does something like this,

```
int j = null;
```

it results in ***Type mismatch : cannot convert null to int.***

Now

```
    Integer i = null;
    int n = i;
    System.out.println(n);
```

Why does printing n results in ***NullPointerException***, even though null is not allowed for primitive datatype.

Why it doesn't resulted in ***Type mismatch : cannot convert null to int.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's `int n = i;` which throws the `NullPointerException` when the `Integer` is unboxed, since the unboxing involves dereferencing the null reference stored in `i`.

Answer (score 3):

An Integer expression can have a null value. If your program tries to autounbox null,it will throw a NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to print `n`. The NPE is thrown on the previous line when you're attempting to unbox null.